# Why can't AjaxControlToolkit find WebFormsBundle?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've been trying to publish a small intranet WebForms application (.NET 4.0) for a few days now and have been following a breadcrumb trail of script errors that has ended here.  Originally the script manager was complaining about not finding 'MsAjaxBundle' referenced in my Site.Master file.  Some searching led me to [this page](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2012/09/20/september-2012-release-of-the-ajax-control-toolkit).  I followed those directions and installed the AjaxControlToolkit and modified my Web.config accordingly.

The site is now throwing this error:

The assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.60919.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' does not contain a Web resource that has the name 'WebFormsBundle'.

If I comment out the WebFormsBundle reference, the site at least renders halfway but does not pull data from SQL into my jqGrid.

I've tried both the September 2012 version of the toolkit as well as the most recent release, and each one throws this error.  This is driving me mad because of course, the site works fine when built and run locally.

Stack trace for further reference:

```
[InvalidOperationException: The assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.60919.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' does not contain a Web resource that has the name 'WebFormsBundle'. Make sure that the resource name is spelled correctly. Make sure that the application references the correct version of an ASP.NET AJAX Framework assembly.]
System.Web.UI.WebResourceUtil.VerifyAssemblyContainsReleaseWebResource(Assembly assembly, String releaseResourceName, Assembly currentAjaxAssembly) +305
System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.ShouldUseDebugScript(String releaseName, Assembly assembly, Boolean isDebuggingEnabled, Assembly currentAjaxAssembly) +91
System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.DetermineResourceNameAndAssembly(ScriptManager scriptManager, Boolean isDebuggingEnabled, String& resourceName, Assembly& assembly) +101
System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.GetUrlFromName(ScriptManager scriptManager, IControl scriptManagerControl, Boolean zip) +105
System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.GetUrlInternal(ScriptManager scriptManager, Boolean zip) +601
System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.GetUrl(ScriptManager scriptManager, Boolean zip) +206
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterUniqueScripts(List`1 uniqueScripts) +204
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterScripts() +449
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.OnPagePreRenderComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e) +125
System.Web.UI.Page.OnPreRenderComplete(EventArgs e) +113
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +8167
```

Declaration of the toolkit:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <%--Framework Scripts--%>
        <%--<asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js"  Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js"  Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js"  Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js"  Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js"  Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js"  Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js"  Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js"  Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />--%>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
        <%--Site Scripts--%>
    </Scripts>
</ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Removing the Name attribute of the scripts that had a relative path fixed the issues with stumbling over them, so those lines are commented out.

Comment: Is the server expecting the WebFormsBundle to be installed in the GAC?

Comment: I'm not sure; how can I tell?  It does not appear to be installed in the server GAC.

Comment: Can you add `ScriptManager` declaration that you are currently using?

Comment: Article you are referencing explicitly tells to remove `WebFormsBundle` reference. I think issue is somewhere in jqGrid setup or in folders security configuration. Have you tried to monitor HTTP requests from problematic page using browser dev tools or Fiddler? Do you have any 40Xs or 50Xs responses from server?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is covered in article you were referencing. If you are using `AjaxControlToolkit` you should use `ToolkitScriptManager` instead of `ScriptManager`. Just replace `ScriptManager` tag and thats all.

Comment: I had changed the tags to use `<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server">` before posting this question.  The problem lies somewhere deeper...